# How to add custom text to vi airline

Tags: linux, vim, neovim, vim-plugin, vim-airline

How can I add custom text to vim airline. like word `evgenimba` in the right botton of the picture below? I have tried to search with various keyword but could not find the solution [image]

Comment: That's [tmuxline](https://github.com/edkolev/tmuxline.vim), not airline.

Comment: yes, thank you.. but how to use it so that I can have my custom text on right bottom like the picture above?

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I can understand why you asked here, getting any info on this was an emmense pain.

This is possible with a few lines added into your init.vim though it may necessitate some minor loss of function or re-organizing of status line contents

You cannot create a new section in vim-airline as [explained in this issue on gh](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/280) however you can alter, add onto, and re-order the current default sections in the vim-airline statusline to add text or otherwise change the statusline

To start, you should choose a section you would like to alter. I found section y the best candidate for this as I don't have any use for it's current function. You will have to move this section to the end though, which I will explain later.

The default order is as shown, with the section names over them. You can find the codes for each function with `:help 'statusline'`
[image: Visual Representation of Statusline Order]

Here are the individual sections pulled from `:help airline` and what is inside them by default

```
  let g:airline_section_a       (mode, crypt, paste, spell, iminsert)
  let g:airline_section_b       (hunks, branch)[*]
  let g:airline_section_c       (bufferline or filename, readonly)
  let g:airline_section_gutter  (csv)
  let g:airline_section_x       (tagbar, filetype, virtualenv)
  let g:airline_section_y       (fileencoding, fileformat, 'bom', 'eol')
  let g:airline_section_z       (percentage, line number, column number)
  let g:airline_section_error   (ycm_error_count, syntastic-err, eclim,
                                 languageclient_error_count)
  let g:airline_section_warning (ycm_warning_count, syntastic-warn,
                                 languageclient_warning_count, whitespace)
```

Be sure to note, when changing from the default you will **replace the entire section** and thus need to re-add any part you wanted to keep. You can find all the codes with the command `help 'statusline'`

To answer your question, one can change the vim airline section with the following configuration inside your init.vim

```
"Create a funtion to get the sections contents, name is irrelevant
function! GetSectionContents()
  " Will be refreshed often
  return 'evgenimba'
endfunction

"Create vim-airline part
call airline#parts#define_function('partName','GetSectionContent')

"Replace section y with output of parts function
let g:airline_section_y = airline#section#create_right(['','partName'])

// move section y in the right side array to the end of the statusline
let g:airline#extensions#default#layout = [
    \ [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
    \ [ 'x', 'z', 'error', 'warning', 'y' ]
    \ ]
```

Here is a screenshot of what I was able to achieve
[image: vim config final with hello world as the output text]

Some good reading on how you can configure a section further is available in `:help airline-advanced-configuration`